# Notification every boot saying "This app is no longer available."

Tags: windows-10, cpu-z

Every login I get this message:

[image: "This app is no longer available" error message]

After a search, it's due to a recent Windows 10 upgrade. The Application Compatibility Manager no longer approves CPU-Z and uninstalled it. Unfortunately I now get this message that I cannot remove. I searched the registry, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Download](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and re-install it. (It should work fine after doing this. There was an issue with a recent Windows 10 update that caused certain hardware-interacting software to be uninstalled. Reinstalling affected software seems to work.) If you still want to remove it, then do a normal uninstall. This should clean up whatever is causing that message to appear.

Comment: I reinstalled then uninstalled and the message vanished. Thanks for your help.